# 405 error in POST method

Tags: java, json

Rest controller:

```
@Path("/json")
public class Second {
    @POST
    @Path("/say")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

A *request call* returns the HTTP status code **405**.

Comment: More details required: what server, version, configuration, calling code

Comment: how are you accessing the endpoint "say"?

Comment: you should clarify which is the request you are doing (parameters and so on).

Comment: server version is tomcat 7@JacekCz

Comment: It's POST request, maybe you are trying to call it via GET request, that is the only issue I guess, otherwise it should work fine.

Comment: i need to post a json data to server..and i need this by using post() method.so i how can i rewrite this program..could you help me to write the code @PradeepSimha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, 405 is method not allowed error. So you need to change it to @GET.
Secondly, if you want to print json, you should use @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
Here are examples of GET method:

```
//GET method to print JSON 
@Path("/say")
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String hello()
{
    return "{\"message\":\"hello\"}";

}
```

or if you have to get plain string(as mentioned in question) then try this:

```
@Path("/say")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello()
    {
        return "hello";

    }
```

For POST methods, you need to pass the data(String in this case) as parameter

```
 @Path("/say")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello(String name)
    {
        return "hello "+name;

    }
```

P.S. Also dont forget to give name attribute to your html input tag

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanku 4 the rply @Ashish Raj...bt GET method is working good...but i am getting error in code using POST method..so could u pls help me to write that code..

Comment: tell me what json you need to post,

Comment: i need to post name which is in text field in my html form.when i click on save button i need this name to see in my server. @ Ashish Raj

Comment: are you using angular or javascript to post it to your REST method? Tell me how you are calling post method

Comment: it would be helpful if u know  any string variable in json to post in server using POST() method @ Ashish Raj

Comment: using Javascript @ Ashish Raj

Comment: I am editing my answer according to this, give a tick if it helps

Comment: still i am getting the same error as before@ Ashish Raj

Comment: do we need html and js page to simply print a plain text string using post method in the server @Ashish Raj